# finding records that the column just has special digit like zero by regular expression in Sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex

I have some records in a SQL Server table that has a `Nvarchar` column.

This column values contains:

1- Combination of character & digits like: `'AA3136381'`

2- Digits like:  `02240773`

But there are some records that the column value contains only 0. like:

### column

0

00

00000000

In this column, the number zero can be repeated many times.

I want to find these records by regular expression in SQL Server query.

I mean the query result set must be:

### Result

0

00

00000000

Not 02240773.

Comment: sql server does not support regular expressions.

Comment: What "special digit" do you mean? `0` is not special, and [`᱐`](https://r12a.github.io/uniview/?charlist=%E1%B1%90) is?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew in the context of this question special just means a particular digit that has special significance

Comment: It's definitely subjective but when I read this question it sounded to me like a person who had a legitimate question, albeit not very well formulated.  It seemed fairly clear that the intent was to filter for records that had a certain pattern of one or multiple 0s in a particular column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
where col not like '%[^0]%'
```

basically, look for anything not a zero, then negate the result

Comment: Thank you so much. That's exactly what I want.

Answer (score 0):

No need for regular expressions (btw. they are very limited in SQL Server). You just need such `where` clause:

```
where len(replace(MyColumn, '0', '')) = 0 and len(MyColumn) > 0
```

which means choose all rrecords, where `MyColumn` is zeros only.

You could also try casting to `int` or better: `bigint` and compare against 0:

```
WHERE CAST (MyColumn AS BIGINT) = 0
```

But it will cause an error, when you have letters inside that column.

Comment: this will incorrectly match empty columns too; I'd suggest casting the value to int and comparing against 0 (ie.   `WHERE  CAST (MyColumn AS INT) = 0`)

Comment: @MikeDinescu But column may contain letters, which would result in error

Comment: you're right -- could probably do a combination of `IsNumeric (MyColumn) AND CAST (..)` or something along those lines